# Link Route53 registered Domain to a CMS system running on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I would like to link Route53 registered Domain to a CMS system running on EC2 instance.

I have registered a domain in AWS Route53. I have a Ghost CMS running on a EC2 instance. Inside the EC2 instance, I have installed Ghost CMS, MySQL Server and Nginx.

When I create **Record Set** to point **public IP** of the EC2 instance to the domain, it points to Nginx default page but not to Ghost CMS.

Can I please know, what am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Did you setup your nginx to point to your CMS?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/ see this can help you. You have to setup server.